Teen/young adult fiction anthology book that has a steampunk/Victorian era theme
I read this book four years ago (in 2020), so the details I can provide may be thin. It was an anthology book that, from what I remember, took place sometime in a Victorian-ish era, with a possibility of steampunk themes.
The first story revolved around a young girl who encountered something that I think was magic related inside the attic/bedroom in her house. I know for sure that, near the end of her first chapter, she was looking out a window and spotted a boy that was running down the street.
In another section of the book, there was also another section based around a small store. I'm not sure of the specific type of store but I think some destruction happened to it.
The last part I can remember was a section related to a factory or most likely a warehouse and someone sending a mechanical bird/drone-like thing to deliver a message to someone.
I have not been able to find this book on Google or any book websites yet. I read it during class, so I wasn't able to keep up with it as the work progressed. It was a fairly decent-sized book though. It also possibly had a time-related title or cover.
